# Java why doesn't my calculation work on this code?

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to run a calculation but I can't seem to put it all on one line, I have to split the result into two seperate lines to achieve the desired result (which seems a bit long winded). 
Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

both x and y are doubles.

Example 1: (incorrect)

```
y=0.68
x= (Math.round(y* 10))/10;
result x=0
```

Example 2: (correct)

```
y=0.68
x= Math.round(y* 10);
x = x/10;
result x=0.7
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: What are the types of `x` and `y`?

Comment: *"which seems a bit long winded"*  Prefer clarity over brevity.

Comment: You think x=7 is a correct result ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.round` returns variable of type `long` (see: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)), which means that the division by `10` is performed on a `long` variable resulting in another `long` variable - that's why you lose the precision.

To make it calculate on it as on `double` and return `double` - you have to cast the result of `Math.round` like this:

```
x= ((double)Math.round(y* 10))/10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to explicitly specify double in your calculation:

```
x = ((double)Math.round( y * 10.0)) / 10.0;
```

[Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) returns a long....

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your snippets, because they don't include variable types, but it's likely to be integer division that's killing you.  When you divide two integers x and y, where x < y, you get zero:

```
int x = 4;
int y = 10;
int z  = x/y; // this is zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
double x = (Math.round(y* 10))/10;
```

`(Math.round(y* 10))` is a long (= 7), which you divide by 10, that gives another long (= 0). The result is then converted back to a double and stored in x.

In your second snippet:

```
double x = Math.round(y* 10);
```

This is equal to 7 and converted into a double. `x / 10` is then a double operation that returns 0.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
y=0.68
x= (Math.round(y* 10)) <--- Evaluated as int since Math.round returns int /10; <-- integer division
result x=0


y=0.68
x= Math.round(y* 10) <-- x is stored as double
x = x/10; <-- double division
result x=7
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because Math.round returns either a long or an int, depending on whether y is double or float. an then you have an integer division.
in the second example x is already a double and that's why you have a double division.